# Thread increases processor usage gradually

Tags: c#, multithreading, multicore, sorteddictionary

I have a .NET thread which is allocated to core #7. The thread function is triggered once in 300ms. Initially it takes around 20-30 ms to execute one call. But this time increases gradually and becomes more than 150ms after some 2,52,000 calls.

Also I have noticed usage of core #7 starts at 10%. By the time the number of calls to the thread function reaches 2,52,000 processor usage of core #7 becomes around 60%. When I stop triggering the thread function, processor usage becomes 0%. But when I start triggering again core usage starts from 60% (not from 0%) and again gradually increases.

I have also noticed there is no memory leak for the application.

Inside my thread function I am combining the elements of two Dictionaries and adding it to another dictionary in a foreach loop. Number of elements in the dictionary will be always 45.

I want this application to be running 24/7. Please let me know some tips to make this processor usage constant.

Comment: You say, "Number of elements in the dictionary will be always 45." Is that the number of elements in each of the three dictionaries? Are you sure that none of the dictionaries is growing? This sounds to me like a dictionary using a custom key type that doesn't implement `GetHashCode` correctly.

Comment: Thanks Jim Mischel,
No. Max count of the combined dictionary is 45. It will be cleared once it reaches 45. Also max count of other two dictionaries never cross 10.

My dictionary is declared as
    `Dictionary<int, MyResult> myResults = new Dictionary<int, MyResult>;`

Comment: Then you'll have to show some code. It's highly unlikely that the threading library is causing this increasing CPU usage. Much more likely it's something in your code.

Comment: please show some source code... otherwise is hard to give any specific answer...

Comment: impossible to help without some code...

Comment: How do I post my function here ? I am not able to post more than 600 characters ....

Answer (score 4):

When you add an item to a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) the capacity may have to be increased. Does your dictionary continue to grow forever?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx):

> If Count is less than the capacity, this method approaches an O(1) operation. If the capacity must be increased to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon Reinhart,
Size of my dictionary never crosses 45.